# MySQL replacing variables in string

Tags: mysql, css, replace

I received some old data of products and in the product description they added their own style to the different products. Its made about 8 years ago. 
Now i got all their own data and I need to remove the styling like the witdh.
The width varies alot so i can be width: 150px to width: 300px ect.

```
<table style="width: 500px;" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
```

I need to remove it so it will become responsive when you scale it down on mobile or tablets.

How should my replace look like? Can i use wildcard to solve this problem or will it just take the rest of the string and delete that aswell?

```
REPLACE(`product_desc`, 'style="width:%"', '')
```

Comment: No you cant use wildcard replace in replace function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pattern is same and you have only `width: Npx;` for the tables then you can do something as below -

```
select 
 replace(
   '<table style="width: 500px;" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">',
   concat(
      'width: ',
      trim( 
        substring_index(
         substring_index(
           '<table style="width: 500px;" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">','width:',-1
         ),
        '"',1
        )
       )
     ),
 '') as a ;
```

The result is

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| a                                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| <table style="" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"> |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can convert this to update statement as

```
update table_name 
set product_desc = 
replace(
   product_desc,
   concat(
      'width: ',
      trim( 
        substring_index(
         substring_index(
           product_desc,'width:',-1
         ),
        '"',1
        )
       )
     ),
 '')
```